# Reactive form for each table row

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using Angular 2 and I want to validate controls in each row separately. But I'm not getting any way to do that. I want it to be done using reactive forms only and not using template-driven approach. I want [formGroup] on each `<tr>`. Any help will be appreciated. Below is the structure of my code:

```html
<tbody *ngFor="let single of allTeamDetails"                
       [ngClass]="{'alternate-row-color': $even}">
  <tr>
    <td class="td-data first-column">
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" 
             [value]="single.first_name">
    </td>
    <td class="td-data second-column">
      <input type="text" class="input-text form-control" 
             [value]="single.last_name">
    </td>
    <td class="td-data third-column">
      <input type="email" class="input-text form-control" 
             [value]="single.email">
    </td>
    <td class="td-data fourth-column">
      <select class="selection-dropdown width-80-percent" 
              [value]="single.user_role">
        <option *ngFor="let singleRole of allUserRole"      
                value="{{singleRole.name}}"> 
                {{setUserRoleAndType(singleRole.name)}}</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td class="td-data fifth-column" >
      <input type="password" class="input-text form-control">
    </td>
    <td class="td-data sixth-column" >
      <input type="password" class="input-text form-control">
    </td>
    <td class="td-data save-send-tm-data">
      <button class="btn save-user-details save-sub-account-details"                                                      
              type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Save">
        <i class="fa fa-floppy-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </button>
    </td>
    <td class="td-data save-send-tm-data">
      <button type="button"                                      
              class="btn save-user-details save-sub-account-details"  
              data-toggle="tooltip" title="Send Message"                       
              (click)="openSendMessageModal(single.email)">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
      </button>
    </td>
  <tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Any solution about this. I was trying using 'ngForm' assigning to dynamic template reference variable but found that template reference variables are static.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `formArray`. What you will do is you create a `formGroup` (master form) that contains multiple, smaller `formGroup`. Each smaller fromGroups will be what is repeated in your `*ngFor`.

Your form should look something like this:

```
<!--This is your master form-->
<form [formGroup]="teamForm">
  <!--Use formArray to create multiple, smaller forms'-->
  <div formArrayName="memberDetails">
    <div *ngFor="let single of allTeamDetails; let $index=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="$index">
        <div>
          <!--your field properties of every repeated items-->
          <input placeholder="First Name" type="text" formControlName="firstName" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input placeholder="Last Name" type="text" formControlName="lastName" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

In your component, you can use angular's `formBuilder` to help to build a the form.

In your constructor:

```
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.teamForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      memberDetails: this.formBuilder.array([])
    });
  }
```

Now you can initialize every property of your repeated models. You can then customise each validators of each field. Note the properties in your typescript file that corresponds to the ones in html. I do all these in `ngOnInit` so that the properties can binded to the html before they are rendered.

```
  ngOnInit() {   
    this.teamForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      memberDetails: this.formBuilder.array(
        this.allTeamDetails.map(x => this.formBuilder.group({
          firstName: [x.first_name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]],
          lastName: [x.last_name, [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]]
        }))
      )
    })
  }
```

After all these, adding validation messages are very trivial. The benefits of doing it this way?

1. because each instance is now a single `formGroup` by itself, you can customize your validation logic down to a very granular level.
2. As the point above, you can subscribe to each `valueChange` of each smaller forms, down to each single field. For example, if you want to subscribe to first team member's first name's field change, you can do this:

   ```
     this.teamForm
      .controls.memberDetails
      .controls[0] //get the first instance!
      .controls.firstName  //get the firstName formControlName
      .valueChange 
      .subscribe(x=>console.log('value changed!))
   ```
3. In the event if you want to validate the master form, you can do so as well.

Have created a [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kjaxo3FQAmjJnP3yfl0w?p=preview), just for you :)

Comment: error loading plnkr