# Angular ngFor radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template-form

I've got a few questions like 'what is something' and 4 radio buttons as answers. So it`s like 3 generated `<ul>`s in DOM. But the problem is, when I click some radio button, it selects the radio button in another question. How to fix this problem? Is it something with the value? Or it needs to have some unique index?

Code:

```
<ul *ngFor="let test of tests"> {{test.question.title}}
    <li *ngFor="let answer of test.question.answers"> <input type="radio" [value]="answer" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected"> <label for="">{{answer}}</label> </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="check(radioSelected)">Send</button>
```

Comment: Please refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44158712/angular-2-reactive-form-for-each-table-row This will help you to solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

add name attribute base of index and create an answer object in the component

component

```
answers = {}; //
```

template (view)

```
<ul *ngFor="let test of tests;let index = index"> {{test.question.title}}
    <li *ngFor="let answer of test.question.answers"> 
       <label >
         <input [name]="index" type="radio" [value]="answer" [(ngModel)]="answers[index]"> 
         {{answer}}</label> 
    </li>
</ul>

<button (click)="check(answers)">Send</button>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-edya7s)

Answer (score 1):

You should have different ngModel for every test in ngFor, change your ngModel to

```
<input type="radio" [value]="answer" [(ngModel)]="test.question.radioSelected">
```

Comment: It catches the answer, but radio is still can be checked only on one question

Comment: Try changing ngModel to answer.radioSelected

Comment: Tried it, doesnt work also. I think the problem is in [value], but which problem I didnt manage;(

Comment: aggray with you about using the `test.question.radio Selected`  as the selection result but I will prefer to use different object because will make working with the result easier 